# SQL Server Conversion failed when converting from date and/or time from character string when query is parameterized

Tags: sql-server

I am curious about this issue.. If I run the following SQL on my SQL Server database:

```
SELECT [id] 
FROM [dbo].[events] 
WHERE createdon BETWEEN '2016-07-09' AND '2016-07-10'
```

It returns events just fine. In this case the `createdon` column is of datatype `datetime`.

When I run that query from ASP.Net I turn it into a paramaterized query.

According to SQL Profiler the following query is then executed:

```
EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT [id] FROM [dbo].[events] WHERE createdon BETWEEN ''@DateFrom''  AND ''@DateTo'' ',
           N'@DateFrom datetime,@DateTo datetime',
           @DateFrom = '2016-07-09',
           @DateTo = '2016-07-10';
```

It looks to me that the query above is the same as the query I originally started with. `@DateFrom` and `@DateTo` are correct set as `datetime` which matches the type of `createdon`.

But the parameterized query fails with:

> SQL Server Conversion failed when converting from date and/or time from character string

I'm wondering why this is? Hoping someone could enlighten me :). Both queries were executed on the same SQL Login. I have added the params via .Net's `command.Parameters.AddWithValue`

(By the way, there will be a time element to the query in the end but I have removed it for simplicity for now).

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in apostrophes `''` around parameters. Most probably you defined your query in ASP.NET like this.

```
string query = "SELECT [id] FROM [dbo].[events] WHERE createdon BETWEEN ''@DateFrom''  AND ''@DateTo'' ";
```

and then add parameters

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateFrom","2016-07-09");
```

ASP.NET consider it as string (`varchar`).
Try this.

```
string query = "SELECT [id] FROM [dbo].[events] WHERE createdon BETWEEN @DateFrom  AND @DateTo ";
//...
cmd.Parameters.Add("@DateFrom",SqlDbType.Datetime).Value = "2016-07-09";
```

### Update

The query in OP (`...BETWEEN ''@DateFrom''  AND ''@DateTo''`) doesn't use values of parameters which may be declared as `datetime` or anything else. It uses `@DateFrom` and `@DateTo` as literals which are not dates for sure.

Comment: Yes that was exactly what I did! Thanks!